# How do I avoid a error if I click on a link from another component while the spinner is running?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't know what to do, what do you recommend?

I made a wheel of names in React and when I click on the spin button in the method I have setInterval and setTimeout which will be executed in for example 10 seconds. 
**During this time you can click on any link from the navigation or back button or manually type the url from another page, BUT when you move to another page while the spin method is executed throws me an error.**

Is there any way to destroy a page if I click on a link from another?

This is a small piece of code that executes successfully if I don't click on the link to go to another page.

The error I get:
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null**

```
   renderSector3(index, text, start, arc) {
   // create canvas arc for each list element
   let canvas = document.getElementById("wheel");
   let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
   let radius = 250;
   let angle = index * arc;
   let baseSize = radius * 1.25;
```

What do you recommend me how to avoid this error, I really have no idea?
If I can get some examples, please help :)

Comment: What error are you getting? Adding some part of your code will help people to help you

Comment: @lissettdm Can this help a little?

Comment: This node document.getElementById("wheel") isn't in the DOM when renderSector3 function is called. Can you add that part?

Comment: @lissettdm It is because multiple methods run in a for loop,
but when i click on some link from another page, the current page goes off and he probably doesn't recognize then canvas?